# Populating dropdown in Play framework

Tags: java, sql-server, playframework

I am fetching a list of client names from database and I need to populate that list to a drop down in the Play framework. When I do, I am getting an error: `not found type name`. What am I doing wrong?

my Application.java code is:

```
package controllers;
import java.awt.List;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;



import play.mvc.*;
import play.twirl.api.Content;
public class Application extends Controller {

    static List l = new List();

    public static <list> Result index() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433","SUMEET","sumeet");
        System.out.println(conn);
        Statement sta = conn.createStatement();
        String Sql = "select * from client";
        ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery(Sql);
        while (((ResultSet) rs).next()) {
         String ID= rs.getString("ClientName");
            l.add(ID);
        }
        return ok((Content) l);



      }

}
```

`

and my `index.scala.html` file is

> ```
>     @import helper._
> @main {
>
>
>             @select(
>                 options(@message), 
>                 '_label -> "Company", '_default -> "-- Choose a company --",
>                 '_showConstraints -> false
>             )
>
>
> }
> ```

Comment: This is completely not understandable for me. I dint see a role of `controller`,`application.conf`,`ebean`

Comment: @singhakash  i have edited the code please can u check and tel how to populate the dropdown in index.html with the list of names fetched from database in application.java

Comment: I can see a lot of problems with your code: using a static list that will be shared by your requests; using List from java.awt; casting that list to Content, etc. You should take a look at [Activator templates](http://typesafe.com/activator/templates) (ex: [Play start app](http://typesafe.com/activator/template/PlayStartApp)) to see how to pass values to your views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  @(ConsultantList:java.util.List[String])
@import helper._
@main("ADAMS") {
---------
---------
@for(element <- ConsultantList){
                <option value="@element">@element</option>
          }
```